# RESTful implementation logic?

Tags: android, ajax, json, apache, rest

I have an online mysql database. I understand that to connect to it from an android app, I need to use a REST web service. From what I understood until now is that I have to use a REST webservice + JSON and Jquery to handle everything. But the things that I dont understand are:

- do I need any coding to be done on my mysql web host domain?
- this REST web service needs to be coded within my android app?
- Do I need an apache http client, and that needs to be coded on my app or on the web host?

Comment: [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/) and plug n play [code](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing database access, server side code and REST.

It is best practice not to go around directly connecting to databases from a client, especially a "locationally diverse" one.

Your architecture may look like

Android app ---HTTPS REST Verbs---> RESTful Webservices on server, hosed on Apache, Tomcat etc. --- Data access, be it via PDO, JDBC, JPA, whatever ---> mySQL.

The RESTful part really is optional, you can call into whatever you like if you're using an URL.

Comment: So I need to install the RESTful webservices on my web host? is this apache httpclient?

Comment: If you're on a LAMP stack based hosting solution, you could implement your RESTful services in PHP. You don't "install" REST as it's a concept. Unless you already have a set of services I'm unaware of.

Comment: So I need to implement a webservice (RESTful) on my hosting solution using PHP code?

Comment: You don't "need" to, only if you "need" REST. You can do what you like effectively, but REST is as good a solution as any as long as you fully understand how to implement it safely. Idempotency of operations can be tricky.

Comment: Thank you. You have set me on a straighter path and I understand things more clearly now.